# Appending a vector inside a double for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, append

I am trying to edit the values inside a vector determined before the loop. I want to append every element in the vector sequentially but can't figure out how to do it.

So here I tried

```
hr <- seq(0,5,1)
hr2 = hr

vec <- vector("list",length = length(hr)^2)

for (x in seq(hr)) {
  for (i in seq(hr2)) {
    vec[[x]] <- i +1
  }
}
```

But this just edits the first 6 elements of the list. I would like to update element 1, then 2, then 3,.... finally element 36.

EDIT: The expected output would be a vector of length 36 with values in each element

Comment: Hi, yes I understand why this error is occurring, The value of x only varies 1-6 but I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect in the end. From *"append"*, I would expect vector-concatenation, such as `vec[[x]] <- c(vec[[x]], i)`. Please provide expected output.

Comment: You'd need something like `vec[[(x-1) * length(hr2) + i]] <- i +1`

Comment: Thank you MrFlick - this worked. If you would like to post your solution I will be happy to mark this as complete.